# Google Analytics Universal Tracking Events: not tracking

Tags: google-analytics

just want to check to make sure I have the correct syntax with the event tracking...

```
ga('send', {
    'hitType' : 'event',
    'eventCategory' : 'links',
    'eventAction' : 'click',
    'eventLabel' : 'sidebar-link',
    'nonInteraction' : 1
});
```

This is used for links that open in a new tag. Also I've found that for links that do not open in a new tag, you can add the member:

```
'hitCallback': function() { document.location = 'http://link-to.com'; }
```

Is this all looking correct? Because I'm not receiving any tracking events on my pages. I checked in debugger, and the code is being called for sure, but nothing is coming up in GA. What's up?

Comment: Are they showing up in the Real Time dashboard? Have you waited at least 24 hours to check?

Comment: Aha, I thought it was supposed to be real-time. I'll wait and see tomorrow I suppose

Comment: You can usually see them come in live in the Real Time view, but you'll have to wait up to 24 hours to see them in your other reports.

Comment: Do you have any updates? I'm facing the same problem: I see my custom event being successfully sent over the network in dev tools (response 200), but it's not showing up in GA.

Comment: Check out my answer below, I was successful with that syntax, and once you get the right syntax in place, wait a day. The results take time to show up in GA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna answer my own question here as I got it working - also I want to provide an example for the alternate syntax, for those who might be confused about it like I was. **Edited for clarity

First off, it was a matter of **waiting for a day** for the results to show up, even in "Real Time" mode.

Second, this is what I went with:

**For links that open in new tab:**

```
//HTML
<a class='newtab' data-type='label-name' href='http://blah.com' target='_blank'>Link to blah</a>

//JS
$('.newtab').click(function(){

    var label = $(this).attr('data-type');

    ga('send', 'event', 'category-name', 'click', {
        'eventLabel' : label,
        'nonInteraction' : 1
    });
});
```

**For links that open in same tab:**

```
//HTML
<a class='sametab' data-type='label-name' href='http://blah.com'>Link to blah</a>

//JS
$('.sametab').click(function(){

    var linkTo = $(this).attr('href');

    var label = $(this).attr('data-type');

    ga('send', 'event', 'category-name', 'click', {
        'eventLabel' : label,
        'nonInteraction' : 1,
        'hitCallback' : function() { document.location = linkTo; }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The part that threw me was in the example where it showed how to add either *all attributes in an object* or *some attributes in the object*, and which attributes were available. Anyway, voila :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe you have the correct syntax. Try this syntax

```
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav buttons', 4); //USE THIS

ga(send, event, eventCategory, eventSction, eventLabel, eventValue) // VARIABLE NAMES
```

**** You do not need to include the event value parameter. All other event parameters are recommended.